# How do I crash Delphi7 Application?

Tags: delphi-7

I like to introduce a crash in Delphi7 Application. I like to do this **to experiment the crash dump** and getting to the same where I introduced the faulty code.

Below is the code which run when a button is clicked on the Form:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x : Integer;
  y : Integer;
begin
  //Try Crashing the WebLink Dll (For a Reserach)
  x:=0;
  y:=0;
  y:= x div y;
end;

end.
```

When I execute the above code in debugger or double clicking the exe, I am getting the below message. But, application is not crashing. Mean, after clicking OK to the dialog, I can click the 'button 1' once again. I do not have any exception handling code. But, how process is not removed from Operating System? What is code I have to write in delphi-7 so that the application will terminate after displaying the crash message

[image]

Comment: Delphi VCL applications have an exception handler that catches such exceptions. So what you are attempting to do isn't going to be possible. For sure you could suppress that exception handler, but your actual program won't be like that. What is the motivation behind the question?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am looking at troubleshooting delphi7 application crash that happens in the field. When the end user gives a crash dump we can analyze it to know the crash location. To study this behaviour, I want to introduce the crash in delphi7 exe, generate crash dump and analyze. I want to check the analyze part goes to the location where I introduced the Crash. But, here application stays in memory even after responding OK to the message. I am not an expert in delphi.

Comment: Going to be hard to do this without becoming an expert in my view. There isn't going to be a quick fix no matter how much you might want one. My advice is to add madExcept to your project and you will be able to receive rich post mortem reports for unhandled exceptions like this.

Comment: You could raise an exception in a plain Win32 thread, for instance.

Comment: "Going to be hard to do this without becoming an expert in my view." - Oh Dave! That's Sad :)

Comment: I would also recommend madExcept